# Unable to uninstall python2 packages on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, package, uninstallation

I'm trying to clear all the packages of python2.7 that were installed using pip.

So I'm using this command:

```
sudo pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Uninstalling pandocfilters-1.4.2:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 68, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 661, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 219, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 273, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandocfilters-1.4.2.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

Comment: Use sudo ......

Comment: Man... Don't do that. Ubuntu needs python and uninstalling the packages can break your system.